# Mapping lakes in an area

Tags: google-maps, geocoding, geospatial, keyword-search

I am working on a project and the very first requirement is to map all the lakes near a location and get their lat/lng. Google map shows lots of lakes but it is tough to zoom and search for several lakes/ponds and note its coordinate manually. How would i use google maps and find all the lakes near a county, location or coordinate.  Help would be very much appreciated.

Thank you!
Vinay

Answer (score 0):

You can create a 1-bit (black and white) image from the map and separate the lakes and the land. Then find the lakes hull.